# Linux thread - simulate a restaurant table

Tags: linux

i need to write a thread that simulates a table in a restaurant.
The table has four seats. At random times customers come and if they
find an empty seat they stay, otherwise they leave.
Can you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: What code have you already written? What do you need help with?

Comment: Is this homework?  Is there more to the problem?  When do people at the table leave?

Comment: I created the thread for the table but i have problems filling it
with people that come and go at random times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudocode:

```
-- A Table Thread

integer num_free_seats := 4

loop forever
   wait for customer c
   if num_free_seats > 0
        seat_customer(c)
        num_freeSeats := num_free_seats - 1
   else
        throw_out_customer(c)
   end if
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need a semaphore initialized to the number of seats at the table.  The people (presumably other threads) check it.  They wait on the semaphore until they get in.  They post as they leave.  If they really need to leave immediately if they don't get a seat then use something like sem_trywait.  Use some kind of randomized sleep for how long they are at the table.